# MS Access - Compact and Repair Large Database

Tags: ms-access

I have a fairly large (1.36 GB) access database I need to run the "Compact and Repair" database tools on. Smaller databases (less than 500 MB) work without issue.

It starts out fine, but I get an error popup that says: "The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2 GB) or there is not enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result".

According to Microsoft, Access creates a copy of the Database, then runs the utility so it could be that in order to compact, the database has to be under 1 GB?

Is there a way to run compact and repair on a large database? Why could you create a database that's 2 GB in size, but can't run a built-in utility on it?

Comment: Any help here http://www.accessrepairnrecovery.com/blog/perform-easy-trim-operation-and-restore-databases-in-ms-access?

Comment: @June7 unfortunately, no...that "article" looks like an ad for their tool and nothing more.

I'm trying to compact it, but it's apparently too large to compact, so that's out the window.

Splitting the Database isn't viable (i don't know what it does, exactly for one) but it didn't reduce the filesize anyway (we're checking the database into source control, plus we're just storing data).

Solution 3 just restates Solution 1.

Solution 4 says "make a backup" -- how's that anywhere close to a solution?

Solution 5 says "buy our product".

The "article" says they have a fix, but...

Answer (score 0):

The only method seems to be:

1. Create a new empty database
2. Import all objects from the current (too large) database
3. Copy specialities like custom properties (if any) from the current database
4. In the new database, do Compile and Save the code modules
5. Check everything, just in case. However, there should be no issues

Comment: Nice chat, but what did you do, and what did you get, please?

Comment: this did nothing, as I said..? my comment seems to be gone, but I did exactly what you'd indicated and wound up with a database larger than the original.

Comment: That, I would say, is not possible, even having autocorrect turned on.

Comment: which, as I said, is absolutely ridiculous. If Microsoft allows us to create a database that's 2GB in size, it should let us run their tools against it.

Comment: Run 1. again. Then 2. just importing one large table. Repeat 1. and 2. for each large table. Finish using 1. and 2. for the remaining objects. Note filesizes. Run a c/r on each file; sizes shouldn't change much if at all. Check that the sum doesn't exceed 2GB. Finally run 1. and then import the individual databases. Note total filesize.